# настройки virtuemart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

День добрый joomla 2.5.16 и VM2.
Не могу найти где поменять страницу категории, где его менять? хочу чтобы при клике на изображение переходило на страничку товара, а сейчас просто фотка увеличивается. Так же при клике на купить товар выскакивает "спасибо за покупку"

1. Разобрался с кликом на изображение.
2. Остался вопрос, как убрать товары слева.

Comment: сайт на локальном хосте или на удалёнке ?

Comment: удаленка faberlem.ru